# How to Scan For Wifi Access Points in C++ on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, network-programming, wifi, firebreath

I need to scan for and gather information about local **Wifi** access points in **Mac OS X** Linux in **C++**. This perhaps uses `Wlan` or something akin to `WlanScan`. I have similar code working in Windows that cannot possibly be translated.

This code is being built in a FireBreath development project.

Do you have an example or suggestion for scanning Wifi access points in C++ on Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this in plain C++, but you can use Objective-C++ (you source file just need to have .mm extension and you can use Objective-C right in your C++ code). Take a look at [CoreWLAN](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CoreWLANFrameworkRef/_index.html) framework.
You should write something like this:

```
#import <CoreWLAN/CoreWLAN.h>

struct AccessPoint
{
    string ssid;
    string bssid;
    int rssi;
};

vector<AccessPoint> ScanAir(const string& interfaceName)
{
    NSString* ifName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:interfaceName.c_str()];
    CWInterface* interface = [CWInterface interfaceWithName:ifName];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* scanResult = [[interface scanForNetworksWithSSID:nil error:&error] allObjects];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ (%ld)", [error localizedDescription], [error code]);
    }

    vector<AccessPoint> result;
    for (CWNetwork* network in scanResult)
    {
        AccessPoint ap;
        ap.ssid  = string([[network ssid] UTF8String]);
        ap.bssid = string([[network bssid] UTF8String]);
        ap.rssi = [network rssiValue];
        result.push_back(ap);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I didn't test this code, but I use similar code in my project, so it should work. Note also that I'm using ARC here. If you'll get some errors - feel free to ask in comments.
There is also [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreWLANWirelessManager/Introduction/Intro.html) in apple documentation, but it is somewhat outdated (it is for OS X 10.6). There were some changes in OS X 10.7.
Note that CoreWLAN framework requires OS X 10.6 or greater.

Comment: Thanks @cody. This looks extremely promising. I see that `scanForNetworksWithSSID` is blocking. Perfect, I am already in an async thread. Are you saying that I can use Objective-C knowing that I am working in FireBreath? (i.e. To your knowledge, will Objective-C work in FireBreath?)

Comment: Regarding Objective-C in FireBreath, this seems to answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325559/how-do-i-add-objective-c-code-to-a-firebreath-project

Comment: sorry, I don't know what FireBreath is, but Objective-C is mostly runtime, and it is native for OS X so I think it will

Comment: [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) is awesome if you need to make cross-platform/cross-browser Internet plugins for web-browsers. One stop shopping.

Comment: Hi @cody. What do you use for `interfaceName`, as the input to `ScanAir()`?

Comment: interface name :) en0, en1

Comment: Ok, thanks. I also believe "network" above should be "item" in three places (i.e. "[[item ssid] UTF8String]"). If I am correct, one of us should edit the answer, above.

Comment: As are you @cody. Your example provided complete success for what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: @code, Do you know how to tell which if any of these networks are currently connected? Do you know the status? This information does not appear in the `CWNetwork` class.

Comment: @DavidManpearl You can ask your interface about it (CWInterface). Properties names are the same. And there will be nil in case if the interface is not connected

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @cody, I had a same requirement I need to list all the available networks and have find other details like IP address , MAC address of each network. Is there any way to get such details.

Comment: @VijayYadav Can't say for sure right now, but I think you can't get this via COREWlan framework. Take a look at SystemConfiguration framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SysConfig/ May be you can get some info from COREWlan, and use it in SysConfig to get the other